# Changing choice of folders in Download Dialog?

Tags: downloads, dialog

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

When I download a file (say e.g., in Firefox), there is a list of "shortcut folders" on the left (e.g. Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos, Downloads [[I would have added image, but the forum won't let me]]).

Is it possible to change this list? In particular, earlier versions used to have "Ubuntu One" as an additional option in this list, which is now missing. I'd like to add that back if possible. Adding "Dropbox" would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the download dialog you can drag folders from the file list on the right into the shortcut list to add them.

Or you can edit the file `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` using a text editor like gedit.

Answer (score 1):

Just bookmark the folder in Nautilus - navigate to it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, or go to the Properties menu:

[image]

It should then appear in the side pane, under **Bookmarks**:

[image]